# Returning a String from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have created a Spinner and ArrayAdapter as follows:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.units_array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

The units_array1 is a string array declared in a xml file like this:

```
<string-array name="units_array1">
    <item>Centimeters</item>
    <item>Meters</item>
    <item>Kilometers</item>
    <item>Inches</item>
    <item>Foots</item>
    <item>Miles</item>
</string-array>
```

Now I want to implement some If-ELSE conditions that are based on the elements in string-array. I Have researched a lot on the internet for this but haven't found out any solution that works. Please help me in implementing a function that returns the individual elements from the string-array using the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id3) {
        final String scale = adapter1.getItem(position);
        // scale is gonna be "Centimeters" or "Meters", etc...
        if (scale.equals("Centimeters")) {
            // do something
        } else if (scale.equals("Meters")) {
            // do something else 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayAdapter.getItem(position)`, where position is the index into the array.  If you want to get the currently selected item in your Spinner, use `Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` as the parameter to `getItem()`.

This will return a `CharSequence` because of you your adapter is typed.  If you want that values to return as Strings, redefined your adapter as `ArrayAdapter<String>`

HTH!

Comment: I want to return the value touched by the user. How should I do that??

Comment: `adapter1.getItem( spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() )`

Answer (score 1):

ArrayAdapter has getItem(int position), which (if you know the position) will get you the String. ArrayAdapter also has getCount(), so you can write a simple for loop to get each element if you don't know its position.

Comment: I want to return the value touched by the user. How should I do that??

Comment: See gwa's or Arhimed's answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `OnItemSelectedListener` to your spinner. Then in the listener you'll be notified about the selection event. Check the official sample on this: [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).

Comment: Now that I have set the OnItemSelectedListener on the Spinner, what function am I supposed to call to return the value clicked??

Comment: @Spoilt: looks like we are not on the same page. :) Ok, what do you mean exactly saying "to return the value clicked"? To return from where to where? In the listener you already got the value, right? So what prevents you from using it for what ever you want needs?

Comment: The example you have quoted is of Toast. I want it to return a String so that I can use it somewhere else. I am lost at this. I tried to create some of my own functions, testing one after the another, but nothing has helped so far.